# Dereferencing in for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Apparently I've had wrong assumption that dereferencing a pointer will always create a temporary object. For ex., in the following piece of code

```
vector<string> *vecptr = new vector<string>();
...populate vector...
for(string& str: *vecptr)
{ //do something }
```

I've always thought *vecptr would create a local temporary object and inefficient. I was averse to dereference in the loop and would do something like

```
for(vector<string>::iterator str = vecptr->begin(); ....
```

for the sake of avoiding dereferencing. I just learned that dereferencing does not create a temporary object in the first case, so there is no need to avoid it. What is the C++ rule that avoids creating temporary object in such a  case. Under a regular case

```
string str = *ptr_string;
```

will copy since *ptr_string is an rvalue in this case? Why is it different with the for loop?

Comment: `*ptr_string` is an lvalue

Answer (score 4):

> so there is no need to avoid it.

Well, there are reasons to avoid indirection when possible. But this "temporary" is not such reason since it's not true.

> What is the C++ rule that avoids creating temporary object in such a case.

There just isn't a rule saying that a temporary object would be created.

> will copy since *ptr_string is an rvalue in this case?

`*ptr_string` is an lvalue; not rvalue. (assuming `decltype(ptr_string)` is `std::string*`; it could be an rvalue for strange overloads of unary * operator for class types).

`string str = ...` will copy because it is copy initialising a value object.

> Why is it different with the for loop?

It's not different with the for loop. You can do the copy with a loop as well:

```
for(string  str: *vecptr)
  //      ^ is not a reference: therefore it is a copy of the element
```

As well as no copy with a "regular" variable:

```
string& str = *ptr_string;
  //  ^ is a reference: therefore not a copy
```

It's also entirely the same even if you hadn't indirected through pointer, but instead used some other lvalue such as a reference or the name of a variable instead.

Comment: Question for clarification. Is decltype(ptr_string) a std::string* ? His template type for his vector pointer is a std::string, not a std::string *. If I am not mistaken, isn't his declaration of his vector an unitialized vector<string> pointer on the stack? It would be pointing to a garbage memory address until it is assigned to another vector or allocated to the heap.

Comment: @PaulRenton `Is decltype(ptr_string) a std::string* ?` They don't show the type, but I assume so based on the name. `isn't his declaration of his vector an unitialized vector<string> pointer on the stack?  It would be pointing to a garbage memory address until it is assigned to another vector or allocated to the heap.` Yes and yes.